# R, Trying to transform a vector of integer to a specific binary Matrix

Tags: r

I would like to transform a vector of integer such:

```
vector = c(0,6,1,8,5,4,2)

length(vector) = 7

max(vector) = 8
```

into a matrix **m** of nrow = length(vector) and ncol = max(vector) :

```
m = 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0

1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

It's just an example of what I am trying to do. I intend that the function work with every vector of integer.

I tried to used the function mapply(rep, 1, vector) but I obtained a list and I didn't succeed to convert it into a matrix...

It would be very useful for me if someone can help me.

Best Regards,

Maxime

Answer (score 1):

If you use `c(rep(1, x), rep(0, max(vector-x))` on each element of your variable `vector` you get the desired binary results. Looping that with `sapply` even returns a matrix. You only need to transpose it afterwards and you get your result.

```r
vector = c(0,6,1,8,5,4,2)
result <- t(sapply(vector, function(x) c(rep(1, x), rep(0, max(vector)-x))))

is.matrix(result)
#> [1] TRUE

result
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0
#> [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#> [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0
#> [6,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
#> [7,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Putting that into a function is easy:

```r
  binaryMatrix <- function(v) {
    t(sapply(v, function(x) c(rep(1, x), rep(0, max(v)-x))))
  }
  binaryMatrix(vector)
  # same result as before
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: That's great! Have a nice day Jan

Answer (score 1):

Another straightforward approach would be to exploit matrix sub-assignment using row/column indices in a matrix form (see, also, `?Extract`).

Define a matrix of 0s:

```
x = c(0, 6, 1, 8, 5, 4, 2)
m = matrix(0L, nrow = length(x), ncol = max(x))
```

And fill with 1s:

```
i = rep(seq_along(x), x)  ## row indices of 1s
j = sequence(x)           ## column indices of 1s
ij = cbind(i, j)          
m[ij] = 1L

m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0
#[6,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
#[7,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all values in the vector are non-negative integers, you can define the following function

```
transformVectorToMatrix <- function(v) {
  
  nrOfCols <- max(v)
  
  zeroRow <- integer(nrOfCols)
  
  do.call("rbind",lapply(v,function(nrOfOnes) {
    if(nrOfOnes==0) return(zeroRow)
    if(nrOfOnes==nrOfCols) return(zeroRow+1)
    c(integer(nrOfOnes)+1,integer(nrOfCols-nrOfOnes))
  }))
}
```

and finally do

```
m = transformVectorToMatrix(vector)
```

to get your desired binary matrix.

Comment: Have a nice day Jonas!!